# Congruence modulo proof

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Statement: a = 1 (mod 5) then a^2 = 1 (mod 5)

Direct proof (we also have the option of proving by contraposition):

let a = 5m + 1

then a^2 = (5m+1)^2  = 25m^2 + 10m + 1 = 5m(5m + 2) + 1

hence a^2 = 1 (mod 5)

is this the correct proof, do i need to add anything extra or am I completely wrong?

Comment: $$5|(a-1), (a-1)|(a^2-1)\implies \cdots$$

Comment: Yes, this is a correct proof.

Comment: One minor detail.  You may want to say that since $a\equiv1\pmod5$, then $a=5m+1$ for some integer $m$.

Comment: @Mike thanks, will add that in.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put this in a comment, but I"m not allowed to yet, too new here.  If you want to be ultra-formal about it, you'd note that since $m\in \mathbb Z$,  then by the closure of the integers under addition and multiplication, $m(5m+2)\in \mathbb Z$.   However,  that's such a trivial, obvious step most people who aren't utterly pedantic won't mind you skipping it :).

Comment: Did you mean ->> 5m(5m+2) <<- belongs to the set of integers? or am I misunderstanding what you wrote? Otherwise thanks for the additional proof writing tip